# Do calculations on child records properties for master record

Tags: formula, master-detail

I am developing data model like master - Order, childs - Order items. There is master-detail relationship. Order items have quantity and price per each item. How do I create read-only field on master record to calculate total amount (sum of amounts of each child multiplied by quantity) **without using trigger**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a custom field on the parent object using the rollup summary data type. The field creation wizard will walk you though it. 
Create a formula field on the child "Total Amount" (quantity * unit price), then sum the formula.

Comment: I am afraid I can't do it this way. Imagine I have one order with one order item - price 1000, quantity - 2. So I want to see total price 2000 on master record. But with rollup summary I can get count or sum, but not multiply price by quantity.

Comment: What about using two hidden custom fields, one for price and one for quantity, with a third to do the calculation?

Comment: @VladyslavKushney Create a formula field on the child "Total Amount" (quantity * unit price), then sum the formula.

Comment: @sfdcfox this worked great